# determine Exchange 2013 role via a cmdlet

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

Is it possible to get the role (mailbox, CAS,...) configured in Exchange 2013 with a cmdlet  for example ?
If no , is there any other way (other than asking the admin) ?
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `get-ExchangeServer`

For example, `Get-ExchangeServer e2013-mbox1.example.com` returns the details of the server named e2013-mbox1.example.com. Just running the command itself without any arguments will dump info on all servers in the organisation.

You can use the usual | ft or | fl to play with the output, or to search for servers holding a particular role, something like:

```
get-exchangeserver | where {$psitem.serverrole -eq "ClientAccess"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer .Is there any other way ?